# ZingChart keeps on loading when I add step:minute

Tags: datetime, zingchart

I have date-time axis vs integer. Whenever I set step: minute, the chart can't be seen, it just keeps on loading, while when I delete it, I can see the chart then. This does not allow me to use the step feature. You can view it on http://alnnovative.com/zingdemo.php Is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a reference error in your page that says `hour is not defined`.

The "step" attribute accepts a numeric or string value.

Change `"step":hour` to `"step":"hour"`